# Enconding temperature for exchange over bluetooth

Tags: python, encoding, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to understand how to encode some data for transfer over BLE (bluetooth low energy).
Specifically, I'm interested in this particular line:

https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/05f95682e7ddfb08c317e83826df9a1d636676f3/ports/nrf/examples/ubluepy_temp.py#L68

Which comes from the snippet:

```
temp = Temp.read()
temp = temp * 100
char_temp.write(bytearray([temp & 0xFF, temp >> 8]))
```

Before we even come to the *why* part, I need to understand the *how*. In this snippet, the temperature is read from a sensor as a float, in Celsius. Let's say "20.00" for now. We then multiply it by 100, and then comes the encoding part:

```
2000 & 0xFF -> 208
2000 >> 8   ->   7
```

So we're basically sending:

```
>>> bytearray([208, 7])
bytearray(b'\xd0\x07')
```

Is this correct? I would say so, I checked it with my own device and this seems to be the data that is being sent, and it also works, I can read the temperature sent from my BLE device.

What I don't understand is why all these bit manipulations are required. For example, I tried to just send `bytearray([hex(20)])` but it doesn't work (when trying to read the temperature from my phone, the data couldn't be parsed/converted).

Could you explain the format of the data sent please?

Comment: `I tried to just send bytearray([hex(20)])` you forgot the *100 part. And the call to `hex` is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the [tests](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/tests/basics/int_bytes.py), the straight forward way to do the conversion in Python is with `to_bytes` and `from_bytes` functionality

Using your data it would be for the bytes to an int direction:

```py
>>> int.from_bytes([208, 7], byteorder='little', signed=True)
2000
```

From int to bytes:

```py
>>> int(2000).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little', signed=True)
b'\xd0\x07'
```

Or from the reading to bytes:

```py
>>> int(20.00*100).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little', signed=True)
b'\xd0\x07'
```

Bluetooth data should be a list or bytearray in [little endian](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html) format. Each integer in the list needs to represent an [octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)).

From the source you linked to I can see the characteristic UUID is `0x2A6E`:

```py
uuid_temp = UUID("0x2A6E")  # Temperature characteristic
```

This is an official UUID so is described in "16-bit UUID Numbers Document" at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/

[image]

There is more detailed explanation in the [GATT Specification Supplement](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/) document on the Bluetooth SIG website in section: "2: Values and represented values". In that document it also explains how to represent Temperature this way:
[image]

Comment: Gotcha, that's what I'm looking for. I assume my smartphone knows it's receiving a temperature because it can read the Characteristic's attribute. So how is the temperature encoded? On these 2 octets that I'm sending? How does the smartphone knows it needs to divide it by 100 before displaying it?